# Find the different content using shell

Tags: shell

Does somebody know how to use shell to compare two files? and find the different content between them, for example, 1.txt contain 1023 name ,  2.txt contain 800, I want to know the different 223 name between 1.txt and 2.txt

Comment: Which shell? Which OS? Sorted or unsorted files?

Comment: Liunx,unsorted files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`comm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?comm)

You'd have to sort the files for it though.

```
sort 1.txt > 1.sorted.txt
sort 2.txt > 2.sorted.txt

comm -3 1.sorted.txt 2.sorted.txt
```

Note that will *also* tell you if there are lines in 2 that are not present in 1. That it holds less lines does not necessarily mean they all exist in 1.

```
# only show lines that are in 1 or 2, but not both
comm -3 1.sorted.txt 2.sorted.txt

# only show lines that are unique to 1
comm -23 1.sorted.txt 2.sorted.txt

# only show lines that are unique to 2
comm -13 1.sorted.txt 2.sorted.txt
```